# How to call a C# dll in ruby?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dll

How to call a C# dll in ruby?

Comment: sounds like a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025086/how-do-i-call-windows-dll-functions-from-ruby

Comment: not a dupe (of the question cited, at least) - that was about calling unmanaged code, this one's about managed.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of a few possibilities:

- Write (or get someone to write) a COM wrapper for your DLL, if it doesn't already have one, then use Ruby's `WIN32OLE` library to call it;
- Take a look at [RubyCLR](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyclr/), one of the authors of which was [John Lam](http://www.iunknown.com/), who went on to work on IronRuby at Microsoft. (I don't think it's maintained any longer, and it may not support .Net versions above 2.0);
- As already mentioned elsewhere, look at using [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/), if that's a technical option for you.

There's a thread on the topic [here](http://www.mombu.com/programming/c-net/t-net-dll-in-ruby-1453524.html). Note that the last post is actually from John Lam (looks like March 2009) where he seems comfortable asserting that RubyCLR is still functional...

Answer (score 2):

You can also write a native -> C# wrapper DLL using managed C++

Export all the functions you want as C calls in the DLL, e.g.

```
extern "C" __declspec ( dllexport ) void CallManagedMethod() {
   Something^ myManagedObject ...
}
```

Then use FFI to call that DLL from Ruby
https://github.com/ffi/ffi

Answer (score 2):

You can use unmanaged exports (https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports)
to create an unmanaged entry in c#.
For example you can created an init_youmodulename, which is required for a ruby extension.
Then you can use require 'youmodulename' to load it in ruby.

This link (https://bitbucket.org/icehuli/sucsexttutorial) has several examples. Although it aims in ruby extensions for Sketchup, it may still be interesting for you to learn how it works.

Answer (score 1):

With IronRuby http://ironruby.net/