# Call ANSI C method from Ruby

Tags: c, ruby, dll

There's a `dll` built with ANSI C. It has some methods that can be exported (`extern "C"`).

Is it possible to call them from Ruby 1.9.3 (or from Ruby on Rails 3.2.3)?

Comment: You will have to use DL module, which is supposed to be internal thus not documented. However you can find some tutorials online.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025086/how-do-i-call-windows-dll-functions-from-ruby

Comment: And next time you ask a question, be specific. For example dll should be dll file in Windows because many people are not so familiar with windows.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Ruby FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi):

> Ruby-FFI is a ruby extension for programmatically loading dynamic libraries, binding functions within them, and calling those functions from Ruby code. Moreover, a Ruby-FFI extension works without changes on Ruby and JRuby.

To see examples on how to call Windows DLL functions you can look in the Wiki:
https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Windows-Examples