# Ruby Win32API lock users screen

Tags: ruby, winapi

I am writing an app in Ruby that will run as a background process on Windows.

At one point in the app I would like it to lock the users screen. I have tried several methods like "system", "exec", backticks, spawning new processes, calling batch scripts, and some other things.

It appears that since this program is running in the background that I don't have access to normal shell commands, and that I will have to use the Win32API to lock the users screen.

How would I use the Win32API to accomplish this?

Comment: What user is your background process running as?  The user in question, the SYSTEM account, or something else?

Comment: It is running as the system account.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I just tested it out, and that was exactly the issue. I feel like a big idiot, when it was something so simple. It was running as the SYSTEM account, of course it couldn't lock the USER account I wanted it to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`LockWorkStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875.aspx).

To do this from Ruby use the `Win32API` class as covered in this topic: [How do I call Windows DLL functions from Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025086/how-do-i-call-windows-dll-functions-from-ruby)

From the documentation of `LockWorkStation`:

> The **LockWorkStation** function is callable only by processes running on the interactive desktop. In addition, the user must be logged on, and the workstation cannot already be locked.

This does mean that your call to `LockWorkStation` cannot be made from a service.